# Tensorflow dataset pipeline for classifying patches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to write a dataset pipeline in `tensorflow` for tagging patches of images. Right now I'm reading from a bunch of tfrecord files where each file has multiple patches, but only one tag. The tag has four classes.

Tensorflow doesn't seem to like it when I pass a singleton through the pipeline. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Value Tensor("args_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) has insufficient rank for batching.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get this use case to work. Here is basically what I'm trying to do. I could use advice on what I should be doing to `y` so that I get one label per patch at the end of the pipeline. It's fine if I need to change the structure of the tfrecord file so that `y` is a onehot encoded vector; I just didn't know if this was necessary.

```py
def parse_func(proto):
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(
        serialized=proto,
        features={'X': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                  'length': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                  'y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)})

    y = tf.cast(features['y'], tf.int32)  # this is just an integer, but maybe it should be a one-hot encoded vector

    X = tf.io.decode_raw(features['X'], tf.float32)
    length = tf.cast(features['length'], tf.int32)
    shape = tf.stack([length, 60, 1])
    return tf.reshape(X, shape), y


def get_patches(X, y):
    X = X[tf.newaxis, ...]

    patches = tf.image.extract_patches(X,
                                       sizes=[1,  128, 60, 1],
                                       strides=[1, 4, 1, 1],
                                       rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                                       padding='VALID')
    patches = tf.reshape(patches, [-1, 128, 60, 1])
    y = repeat_so_that_there_is_one_label_per_patch(y)
    return patches, y


dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices('tf_record_file_paths')
           .shuffle(100)
           .interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x), cycle_length=4)
           .map(parse_func)
           .map(get_patches)
           .unbatch()
           .shuffle(100)
           .repeat()
           .batch(64, drop_remainder=True)
           .prefetch(1))
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yep. Just posted the answer @jtlz2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this as follows:

```py
def repeat_so_that_there_is_one_label_per_patch(y, patches):
    num_patches = tf.shape(patches)[0]
    tiled_y = tf.tile(y, multiples=[num_patches])
    return tf.reshape(tiled_y, tf.shape(y) * num_patches)
```